# pandas dataframe to json with multiple keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| id | x1 | x2 | x3 | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23432 | example1 | 1 | name | Create |
| 678786 | example2 | 1 | name | Create |

How can I convert that pandas dataframe to this json format?

```
[
  {
    "action": "Create",
    "payload": {
      "id": "23432",
      "x1": "example1",
      "x2": "1",
      "x3": "name"    
    }
  },
  {
    "action": "Create",
    "payload": {
      "id": "678786",
      "x1": "example2",
      "x2": "1",
      "x3": "name" 
    }
 }
]
```

I have played around with pd.json_normalize but can't get it to work. I also referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123002/a-dataframe-with-two-index-to-json-in-pandas) question but it's a bit different due to the need for groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

# intialise data of lists.
data = {'id':['23432', '678786'],
        'x1':['example1', 'example2'],
        'x2':['1', '1'],
        'x3':['name', 'name'],
        'action':['Create', 'Create']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(json.dumps(df.apply(func=lambda x:{'action':x.action,'payload':x[['id','x1','x2','x3']].to_dict()},axis=1).to_list()))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind typing out the columns one solution can be:

```
df['payload'] = df[['id','x1','x2','x3']].to_dict(orient='records')
df_json = df[['action','payload']].to_json(orient='records')
print(df_json)
```